# How do I set pandas dataframe cells equal to based on column values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my issue, I have two pandas dataframes, all with the same column names, and the same number of rows. Below is a sample of what each dataframe would look like.
[Pandas Dataframe Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xemZF.png)

Let me call my dataframes DF1 and DF2. I need to take the "PosRank" value from DF1 and set it equal to the "PosRank" of DF2 at the row where the "names" are the same. There is no guarantee they will be in any sorted or matching order but all names in DF1 will also be in DF2 and visa versa, and will only appear once in each.

Comment: Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: I forgot to mention: _Here is my issue_ No, that's not an issue, that is a goal or objective. What we need to know is what specifically is stopping you from reaching that goal.

Comment: Was this of help?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it. Pay attention to the links in comment

Lets try this one where we use [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['DeAngelo William','Michael Turner'],'PosRank':[1.0,2.0]})
```

df1

[image]

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['DeAngelo William','Michael Turner'],'PosRank':[3.0,6.0]})
```

df2

[image]

Let us create a dictionary with `Name`  from `df2` as key and `PosRank` from `df2` as value

```
d=dict(zip(df2.Name,df2.PosRank))
```

Now map values from `df2` to `df1`

```
df1.PosRank=df1.Name.map(d)
```

New df1

[image]